# Make phpunit catch php7 TypeError

Tags: phpunit, php-7

I am trying to validate that a php7 function accept only integers.

This is the class:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class Post
{
    private $id;

    public function setId(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

And this is the test:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class PostTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private function getPostEntity()
    {
        return new Post();
    }

    public function testSetId()
    {
        $valuesExpected = [123, '123a'];
        foreach ($valuesExpected as $input) {
            $this->getPostEntity()->setId($input);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

`TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Post::setId() must be of the type integer, string given, called in /path/test/PostTest.php on line 35`

Is it possible to validate such error? also, does it make any sense to run such a check?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can test for `TypeError` the same way you would use [for any other exception](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions).

However, I would not test that PHP emits a type error in case of a type mismatch. This is the kind of test that becomes superfluous with PHP 7 code.

Comment: Could you give details about the superflous aspect of testing type mismatch? Why is it useless to check that I did not forget to add a type hint to `myMethod()`'s first argument, for instance?

Comment: This does not appear to be the case. From your own documentation: `By default, PHPUnit converts PHP errors, warnings, and notices that are triggered during the execution of a test to an exception.` It seems you would need `@expectedException PHPUnit\Framework\Error` to expect any PHP `Error`s (including `Error`s emitted via PHP 7 `assert()`), which is counter-intuitive to say the least.

Comment: could you explain (maybe with a documentation referral) how to solve this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48486568/catch-an-error-as-exception

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
$this->expectException(TypeError::class);
```

Comment: Any useful reference? doc and etc?

Comment: That doesn't fix anything because as mentioned above TypeError is NOT a subclass of Exception.

Comment: @CalamityJane it certainly is at least in PHP 7.2

Comment: in 2017 I worked with Php7.0, glad if it is fixed in PHP 7.2!

Comment: `$this->expectException(TypeError::class);` did worked in PHP 7.0.33, 7.1.33, 7.2.30, 7.3.17 and 7.4.5. Here's the proven repo: https://github.com/KEINOS/Practice_PHPUnit-test-of-TypeHint Thanks. But unfortunately @pawel-ploczek's `$this->expectError(TypeError::class);` did not even the latest PHP (7.4.5). 

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, `TypeError` **is not** a subclass of `Exception` ([reference](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php)), whilst it extends `Error`. The only thing they are really sharing is the the `Throwable` interface. The ThrowMatcher can't actually catch a TypeError.

> If you look at the code in
>   [`src/PhpSpec/Matcher/ThrowMatcher.php`](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/blob/af867af3105c5292083263eeca9310a14e1f34d4/src/PhpSpec/Matcher/ThrowMatcher.php),
>   you can see that PHPSpec catches Exceptions that inherit '`Exception`'
>   and then checks the instance type of that exception.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34575347/1977778).

Answer (score 2):

For newer PHP versions try:

```
$this->expectError(TypeError::class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use :

> $this->expectError(TypeError::class);

But dont forget to put it **BEFORE** your function call

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and was trying to catch the `TypeError`, but PHP wasn't throwing it at all. It turned out, that for some reason `error_reporting` directive was set to exclude `E_NOTICE`.

When I set `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` in `php.ini`, it started to work as expected. So, just make sure the likes of `E_ERROR`, `E_WARNING`, `E_NOTICE` are not excluded in your `error_reporting` setup.