# PHPSpec Catching TypeError in PHP7

Tags: php, tdd, php-7, phpspec

I want test an example method with scalar type hinting and strict types in PHP7. When I don't pass an argument, the method should throw a `TypeError`. PHPSpec return fatal error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Example::test

```
<?php

class Example
{
    public function test(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}


class ExampleSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType('Test\Example');
    }

    function it_check_test_method_when_not_pass_argument()
    {
        $this->shouldThrow('\TypeError')->during('test');
    }
}
```

At the beginning I declare: `declare(strict_types=1);`

What is wrong? How do I test throwing `TypeError`?

Comment: So the exception is thrown but uncaught? Or it's not being thrown and it should be?

Comment: Method throw TypeError and I want catch TypeError.  I want use $this->shouldThrow('\TypeError')->during('test'). This method in PHPSpec works when method return Exception but not TypeError.

Comment: Are you using the very latest version of PHPSpec?

Comment: Version PHPSpec is 2.4.1

Comment: It's possible that this is a bug in PHPSpec, and you should report it to them! `TypeError` inherits from `BaseException` rather than `Exception`, so it's possible that PHPSpec is only catching Exceptions that inherit from `Exception`.

Comment: Btw check my answer edit. Someone reported it as a bug, you should chime in on it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me it works if I annotate the unit test with this:

```
/**
 * @expectedException \TypeError
 */
```

Then my test is green.

Comment: This just returns `Failed asserting that exception of type "\TypeError" is thrown.` now.

Answer (score 6):

Upon further investigation, this is a PHPSpec bug, and has been reported [here](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/issues/769). The bug hasn't been fixed in several months, so I would suggest commenting on it.

If you look at the code in [`src/PhpSpec/Matcher/ThrowMatcher.php`](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/blob/af867af3105c5292083263eeca9310a14e1f34d4/src/PhpSpec/Matcher/ThrowMatcher.php), you can see that PHPSpec catches Exceptions that inherit '`Exception`' and then checks the instance type of that exception. But, `TypeError` doesn't inherit from `Exception`, it inherits from `Error`. The only thing it has in common with an `Exception`, is that they both implement the `Throwable` interface.

For example:

```
101     public function verifyPositive($callable, array $arguments, $exception = null)
102     {
103         try {
104             call_user_func_array($callable, $arguments);
105         } catch (\Exception $e) {
106             if (null === $exception) {
107                 return;
108             }
109
110             if (!$e instanceof $exception) {
111                 throw new FailureException(sprintf(
112                     'Expected exception of class %s, but got %s.',
113                     $this->presenter->presentValue($exception),
114                     $this->presenter->presentValue($e)
115                 ));
116             }
```

Report the bug, explain these details, and show them [this documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php) about the inheritance of `TypeError`.

Comment: I reported that bug. I don't know when this bug will be fixed.

Comment: @Matrix12 You can catch(Error $e) to catch Errors... or any specific class that interfaces Throwable