# Catch an error as exception

Tags: php, error-handling, phpunit, xunit

Given the following code:

```
<?php

class Language
{
    private $code;

    public function __construct(string $code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }
}

$lang = new Language();
```

I will get an ArgumentCountError like this:

```
Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments
```

Now I would like to test and ensure this beahviour with a phpUnit unit test like this one:

```
class LanguageTest
{
    public function testLanguageConstructorWillRequireACode()
    {
        $language = new Language();

        $this->expectException(MissingArgumentException::class);
    }
}
```

But php interpeter raise an error and not an exception.

What would be the most idiomatical and correct way to do this?

Comment: As the constructor accepts 1 parameter, either create object of class `Language` by passing one parameter or provide a default value to the parameter.

Comment: OP states that an ArgumentCountError is thrown. The test expects a MissingArgumentException, so this expectation will never be fulfilled